# How add accents in pylatex?

Tags: python, pythontex, pylatex

Hi I'm starting to use pylatex. I'm trying to generate a pdf using the code below but just works when I remove the accent from the word `información` but if I do not remove it promts an Error.

```
        geometry_options = {"tmargin": "1cm", "lmargin": "1cm"}
        doc = Document(geometry_options=geometry_options, )
        doc.packages.append(Package('booktabs'))
        package = Package('babel', options='spanish')
        doc.preamble.append(Package('babel', options='spanish'))
        doc.preamble.append(Command('title', 'Resultado'))
        doc.preamble.append(Command('selectlanguage', 'spanish'))
        doc.preamble.append(Command('author', 'N'))
        doc.preamble.append(Command('date', NoEscape(r'\today')))
        doc.append(NoEscape(r'\maketitle'))

        with doc.create(Section('Resultados')):
            with doc.create(Subsection('Validaciones')):
                doc.append('¿Por que no puedo agregar acentos?')

            with doc.create(Subsection('Validaciones de información')):
                doc.append('')
        doc.generate_pdf('Resultados', clean_tex=False, compiler='pdflatex')
        tex = doc.dumps()
```

Error:

```
$ python val_format.py
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "val_format.py", line 272, in validation
    doc.generate_pdf('Resultados', clean_tex=False, compiler='pdflatex')
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pylatex\document.py", line 247, in generate_pdf
    output = subprocess.check_output(command,
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 411, in check_output
    return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 512, in run
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['pdflatex', '--interaction=nonstopmode', 'D:\\Relations\\Resultados.tex']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (MiKTeX 20.6.29)
entering extended mode
(D:/Relations/Resultados.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 5
L3 programming layer <2020-06-18>
(C:\Users\ricardo.arias\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\article.cl
s
Document Class: article 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX document class

(C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\size10.clo
))
(C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\fontenc.st
y)
(C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\inputenc.s
ty)
(C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/lm\lmodern.sty)

(C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\textcomp.s
ty)
(C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/lastpage\lastpa
ge.sty)
(C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/geometry\geomet
ry.sty
(C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\keyval
.sty)
(C:\Users\ricardo.arias\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/iftex\ifvtex.
sty
(C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/iftex\iftex.s
ty))
(C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/geometry\geomet
ry.cfg))
(C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/booktabs\bookta
bs.sty)
(C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/babel\babel.s
ty
(C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/babel\babel.d
ef
(C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/babel\txtbabe
l.def))
*************************************
* Local config file bblopts.cfg used
*
(C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/arabi\bblopts.c
fg)
(C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/babel-spanish\s
panish.ldf))
(C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3backend\l3bac
kend-pdfmode.def)
No file Resultados.aux.
(C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/lm\t1lmr.fd)
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: pdftex
(C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/lm\ot1lmr.fd)
(C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/lm\omllmm.fd)
(C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/lm\omslmsy.fd)
(C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/lm\omxlmex.fd)
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 24--49


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 24--49


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 24--49


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 24--49


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 24--49


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 24--49


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 24--49


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 24--49


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 24--49


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 24--49


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 24--49


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 24--49


Package lastpage Warning: Rerun to get the references right on input line 55.


AED: lastpage setting LastPage
! I can't write on file `Resultados.pdf'.
Please type another file name for output
! Emergency stop.
<to be read again>
                   \endgroup \set@typeset@protect
l.55 \end{document}

!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on Resultados.log.
```

How can I make a better code and add anything to let me work with accents?
Thanks for read.

Comment: the error shown is not related to anything in the latex file `! I can't write on file \`Resultados.pdf`  means that the file is being blocked by the operating system. Some pdf readers (notably acrobat reader) lock the file for writing, so if you are viewing the pdf file, close the viewer first.

Comment: I can verify that the example document in the question works (after adding `from pylatex import *` at the start) and that the accents are visible in the pdf.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers. I solved closing the pdf file and after adding `from pylatex import *` but what if I want to optimize the code?. I mean, I believe that using `from pylatex import *` is using much more time than just specifying the package I need to. @Marijn

Comment: @Richard21 of course you can make the import a bit more specific by including only the things you actually use, or don't use `from` and just `import pylatex` and then in the code use prefixes like `doc = pylatex.Document()`. The `import *` was just a quick way for me to test your code without needing to check exactly which elements of the library you use. However, Python imports in general are very fast, so I don't think you will notice the difference in loading times between the various methods in practical use cases, [...]

Comment: [...] except maybe if you are generating thousands of documents in a short amount of time. But even then the processing time needed by LaTeX itself will be the deciding factor, and not the library loading procedure in Python.

Comment: Thanks for the info. @Marijn